# Implementing a dynamic height on UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UITableView` embedded in a `UIViewController`. The `TableViewCells` are rows for the user to select something, so when they touch it a checkmark appears, heres where my question comes in:

I dont want the `UITableView` to scroll in its window, I want the TableView to grow with the items it contains. Do I need to put a scroll view on the `UIViewController` and then the TableView on that? Or will the `ViewController` scroll if the content is bigger than the View?

Also, Im not even sure where to start with changing the height dynamically of the `UITableView`, everywhere I look its about changing the cell heighets dynamically.

Please Help! Thank you!

Comment: So you want a table view that only scrolls when it gets bigger than the container view?

Comment: no no, i dont want it to ever scroll, i want the container view to scroll if need be, not the tableview itself.. you know what i mean? So the tableview would essentially be static.

Comment: Not really... So you want a view scrollable underneath a table view?

Comment: Yes, I basically want a list of options to select, but i would rather the view scroll instead of the list be restricted in size and scroll..

Comment: I don't think OP understands that `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`.

Comment: You want a tableView which is fixed and not scrollable, and then cells in that tableView that are scrollable for themselves. If I am right, I would say you are trying to implement something that is interesting but not userfriendly. The screen is too small. You restrict each cell's view to a very small portion of the whole screen. If you are thinking of expanding the selected cell to cover the whole screen, then why not pushing or inserting a new view? That's more user-friendly. You may use custom animation to get the feeling as if the cell is expanding.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.tableView.scrollEnabled=false;
```

stops the scrolling

```
self.tableView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, (float)width, (float)height);
```

sets the size of your tableview

But I don't understand why you want to stop tableview scrolling and to scroll the whole view....

Comment: well maybe theres an easier way to do it then... I have a view where I want a user to name something and then choose options to include ... so think of a UITextField followed by a table of objects which can be selected, clicked on and checkmark appears... I just would think it would be more appealing to the eye if it was a static list if you will.. instead of a box that only shows like 5 options and you have to scroll through up or down to select more things to include, do you know what i mean? Is there a better way to do this? its an embedded UITableView

Comment: so its not the full width and length of the page

Comment: @gamBit Is there any other content on the view? Maybe you could use a grouped tableview with 2 sections, in the first section just one tableviewcell with a textfield in it, and in the other section all your options. I think this would be the better way

Comment: http://d1xzuxjlafny7l.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Add-Player-screen.png

Maybe watch this for getting an idea of what I mean, in the first section is an tvCell with textfield in the other section a normal cell, you could add lots of other cells to the second section, this is just an example

Comment: ok I was thinking of that too actually, Ill try that and let you know how it goes! thanks!

Comment: @gamBit for this you have to add  [mytextview becomeFirstResponder] on  tebleview didSelectRowAtIndexPath